# Laravel excel import excel with rows as column

Tags: laravel, phpexcel

I have a different Excel sheet provided by the vendor. I have attached the image as a reference. Here, I want to insert it in the database in the format below. I could not find any documentation that does this straightforward. Any reference would be helpful.

Excel format
[image]

Import as below format:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Import Export to Excel In Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695100/how-to-import-export-to-excel-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Excel treats the import as one instantiation that loops over all the rows of the file in that same instantiation. So when you do this:

`Excel::import(new CountryImport, $request->country_data);` (where the $request->country_data is your file) then you can run conditional logic on it in the import.

For example, if you are wanting to save it into a database, you could use the `ToModel` implementation:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
class CountryImport implements ToModel
```

then the rest of your code could look something similar to this:

```
public $countryColumns = [];
public $countryColumnAbbreviations = [];
public $currentRow = 0;

public function model (array $row){
    $rowColumnIndex = 0;
    while($row[$rowColumnIndex] != ""){
        if($this->currentRow == 0){
            if($rowColumnIndex > 0){
                $this->countryColumns[$rowColumnIndex] = $row[$rowColumnIndex];
            }
        }
        else if($this->currentRow == 1){
            if($rowColumnIndex > 0){
                $this->countryColumnAbbreviations[$rowColumnIndex] = $row[$rowColumnIndex];
            }
        } else {
          return new CountryDatabaseEntry([
                'country_name' => $this->countryColumns[$rowColumnIndex],
                'country_code' => $this->countryColumnAbbreviations[$rowColumnIndex],
                'weight' => $row[0],
                'rate' => $row[$rowColumnIndex]
            ]);
        }
        $rowColumnIndex++;
    }
    $this->currentRow++;

}
```

So what's going on in this snippet? I'm keeping track of the current row using `$currentRow`. From there, if the current row is equal to zero (the first row), then we loop over the `$row` columns (provided by lara-excel) until we find an empty string. This would indicate the column headers have ended and you're out of countries. Each header gets its value appended to the `countryColumns` array. Exact same logic if the current row is equal to 1 except we append it to the `countryColumnsAbbreviations` array instead. Because we're using the `$rowColumnIndex` to explicitly assign array keys, everything should always be consistent. Then, if the current row is not 0 or 1, we use `$row[0]` to get the weight since that's always in the first column and then add the rate based on which column we're iterating over at the moment.

Naturally since I don't have one of your csv's to test out, I can't fully validate the functionality of this code but I think it can get you on your way with no issues. You can probably be more creative than me and use only 1 array for the countries and their codes by keying the name by the short-code but for readability, and time sake, I just offered the solution I chose here. Let me know if this helps out!